# C#. Почему в Концепции DDD описывают работу с абстрактным репозиторием только в типах AgregationRoot?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, архитектура, ddd

Здравствуйте начитался про DDD и одно из ЖЕСТКИХ требований следования этой концепции это работа с репозиторием только в типах "Корень Агрегации"

```
 public abstract class Repository<T> where T : AggregateRoot
 {
   public T GetById(long id)
   {

   }      
   public void Save( T aggregateRoot)
   {

   }
 }
```

Есть модель предметной области (суб домен) справочник для оценочных компаний.
Бизнес логики внутри домена мало, больше нужна система хранения с CRUD операциями,  но тем не менее полноценный домен выделить можно.
Каждая компания содержит список Домов для оценки, у каждого дома есть набор свойств и бизнес логики.

P.S. В примере, сознательно, указываю простую доменную модель (публичные  get, set для свойств).

```
базовые классы:
DomainEntity - содержит Id, объект мутабелен
DomainValueObject - НЕ содержит Id объект имутабелен.

public class Company : AggregateRoot
{    
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<House> Houses { get; set; }    
}

public class House : DomainValueObject<House>
{     
    public string City { get; set; }                // Город
    public string District { get; set; }            // Район
    public string Street { get; set; }              // Улица
    public string Number { get; set; }              // Дом

    public int? Year { get; set; }                  // Год постройки
    public string MetroStation { get; set; }        // Ближайшая станция метро
    public string Geo { get; set; }                 // гео координаты
    public WallMaterial WallMaterial { get; set; }

    //бизнес логика......
}

public class WallMaterial : DomainValueObject<WallMaterial>
{
  public string Name { get; }  

  //бизнес логика......
}
```

В моем примере Company - это корень агрегации

1. Чтение всех домов этой компании. мне придется тянуть всю компанию.

   ```
    var company= companyRepository.GetById(1);//Тут все зависимости (полный объект Домена)
    var houses= company.Houses;
   ```

На это у DDD есть ответ, делать Dto для возвращаемых объектов (в частных случаях).

```
var housesDto= companyRepository.GetAllHousesDto();
```

Возвращается не House а его подделка, для соблюдения концепции - нельзя работать с агрегатом по частям, а только через Корень агрегации.
housesDto не является частью агрегата, это его подделка.
Тут, понятно и не сильно больно следовать этой концепции.

2. Добавить новый дом.

Т.е. добавляя новый, дом мы взаимодействуем через корень агрегации: 
Я так понимаю предполагается такое использование репозитория

```
  var company= companyRepository.GetById(1);
  company.Houses.Add(newHouse); 
  companyRepository.Save(company);
```

Т.е. чтобы мне добавить дом, мне нужно вытянуть из БД компанию, со всеми зависимостями, добавить дом и потом сохранить.
  Но ведь это не оптимально? зачем мне лишняя операция чтения?

по классике (если использовать EFcore в качестве технологии хранения) делаем так.

```
public async Task<bool> AddHouseInCompanyAsync(long companyId, House house)
{
    var efHouse = Mapper.Map<EfHouse>(house);
    efHouse.EfCompanyId = companyId;
    var res= await _context.Houses.AddAsync(efHouse);
    return res.State == EntityState.Added;
}
```

Но это уже нарушение DDD, в методе репозитория используется часть агрегата (House).

Как быть? изменять объект всегда через company (т.е. через корень агрегации)?
Или для моей задачи не подходить DDD и лучше использовать CRUD обертки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего, ещё раз взгляните на сценарии использования вашей программы. Возможно, *дома* в вашей предметной не являются частью *компании*, а отдельными *сущностями*, своими собственными *агрегатами*.

Агрегат это составной объект. Например, в интернет-магазине агрегатом может быть сущность *заказ*, в которой есть отдельные *товарные позиции*, которые без заказа бесполезны. Косвенно вложенность товарных позиций подтверждают сценарии использования и соответствующие им экранные формы. Есть форма редактирования заказа в которой представлены все товарные позиции, но нет формы редактирования отдельной товарной позиции.

Если в вашей программы есть формы редактирования отдельного дома без всякой связи с компанией, значит, *дом* это выделенный *корень агрегации*.

Агрегаты могут ссылаться друг на друга, но только через идентификаторы. Содержать друг друга они не могут.

DTO из репозиториев возвращать не надо. Обычно, DTO формируются где-то вне предметной области для связи с другими слоями приложения. В самой предметной области у вас только *сущности* и *объекты-значения*, объединённые в *агрегаты*.

По поводу *лишней операции чтения* при добавлении нового дома. DDD это не про оптимизацию, а про упрощение архитектуры, упрощение кода и упрощение сопровождения. В DDD репозитории читают из базы не часть сущности, и не просто сущность, а все связанные сущности, объединённые в агрегат.

Велика ли потеря скорости? Нет. Есть такой паттерн, *Remote Façade*, описанный Фаулером. Основанием для его использования является особенность загрузки данных с удалённых компьютеров, а именно наличие так называемой *задержки*. При установке соединения с сервером мы тратим небольшое время, а после того, как соединение установлено, можем получать данные на большой скорости. Поэтому полезно читать чуть больше данных, чем нам может быть нужно, это будет быстрее, чем прочитать два или три раза ровно столько данных, сколько нам нужно.

Кроме того, если мы захотим перейти с реляционного хранения на документное, интерфейсы репозиториев не изменятся, слой предметной области вообще не придётся менять. Поэтому не бойтесь лишних чтений.

В EF для подгрузки связанных данных используется метод `Include`. Предположим, что всё-таки дома это часть компаний. Тогда при загрузке компаний нужно загрузить связанные дома:

```
public class CompanyRepository
{
    private readonly DbContextFactory dbContextFactory;
    private readonly DataMapper dataMapper;

    . . .

    public Company GetById(long id)
    {
        using (var dbContext = dbContextFactory.Create())
        {
            var companyData = dbContext.Companies
                                       .Include(x => x.Houses)
                                       .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

            var company = dataMapper.FromData(companyData);

            return company;
        }
    }
}
```

Благодаря методу `Include` из базы будет загружена не только компания, но и дома, которые к ней приписаны. В этом коде видно, что мы загружаем DTO и отдаём их в объект `DataMapper`, который строит из них агрегат целиком, включая сущности `House` внутри `Company`.

Comment: Спасибо, вы подтвердили, что нужно работать только с целым агрегатом, как вы написали в примере так я и использую репозиторий, как обертку над EF. Вы написали что если дом это агрегат и корень агрегации, то тогда Компания может содержать только список ссылок на дома List<int> HousesId ?

Comment: Паттерн Remote Façade приминительно к WebApi - этот чо-то типа кеша (например Redis). Если читать не только, то что нужно, а больше, значит это где то нужно хранить между запросами и как то перезаписывать если произошла операция записи и данные поменялись. Звучит как кеш для БД.

Comment: @Aldmi 1. Да, агрегаты, если ссылаются на другие агрегаты, хранят у себя их идентификаторы. Обычно, если у вас сложный сценарий, вы создаёте *службу* *прикладного уровня*, загружаете несколько объектов из нескольких репозиториев, и выполняете нужные операции над ними, часто в рамках одной транзакции.

Comment: Метод Save() в репозитории  DDD заменяет методы Add() и Update(). т.е. остаются Get методы - возвращающие весь агрегат. remove() - удаляет весь агрегат, Save() - Добавляет новый (если Id не заданно) или изменяет имеющийся агрегат (Id заданно).

Comment: @Aldmi Remote Façade это точно не про кэш. Хранение между запросами это другие сценарии, могут иметь место, могут не иметь. Remote Façade это про то, что не нужно бояться загружать данных, лишние в данном конкретном сценарии, это может оказаться даже быстрее, и уж точно будет проще в сопровождении.

Comment: службу прикладного уровня - это на слое ApplicationLayer? В данном примере у меня Суб домен - это справочник. Другой Суб домен это заказы, я планирую на каждый суб домен создавать отдельную БД (как будто это микросервис). Пока в голове нет полного понимания как работать с суб доменами и на каком слое приложения. Подскажите где про это почитать.

Comment: @Aldmi 3. Что касается метода `Save`, то тут возможностей много. Вы можете использовать у себя паттерн *Unit of Work* (UoW, *единица работы*), или можете обходиться без него. Это зависит от сложности сценариев. Без UoW методы `Remove`, `Update` будут в хранилище, а с ним — в объекте UoW.

Comment: @Aldmi Я не очень понимаю, что такое Субдомен. В DDD есть понятие bounded context, то есть часть предметной области, с которой мы работаем. Это оно?

Comment: При загрузке FrontEnd приложение как правило читает как можно больше инфы для себя с WebApi. Но во процессе работы если мы поменяли адрес в одном доме и полетел запрос на это изменение, зачем мне загружать 10 компаний вместо 1, если контекст существует только на время жизни запроса. значит эти 10 лишних компаний нужно где-то хранить между запросами?

Comment: да Суб домен с точки зрения кода это bounded context

Comment: UoW же объединяет работу с несколькими репозиториями под одной сущностью. Как метод Remove, который относится к конкретному ре позиторию может быть в нем? Я выношу в UoW  методы  для транзакций например SaveChange() применить для всех репозиториев, или я чо-то не так понял?

Comment: Я так понял не критично оставить в репозитории методы Add(agregationRoot ag) и Update(agregationRoot ag). Тут как больше нравится? Если использовать EF как технологию хранения, то метод Update() сам знает обновить текущую сущность со всеми связями (если есть Id) или добавить если нет Id. И при таком сценарии логичнее использовать один метод Save() для репозитория. и если использовать Uow то подтвреждать действия методом SaveChnages()

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91024/discussion-between-aldmi-and-mark-shevchenko).

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно поняли идею с корнем агрегации и остальными сущностями.

Если сущность *может* существовать без корня - она сама корень.

Если дома могут существовать без компании - они тоже корни.

Пример корня на вашей предметке:

Этажи дома - должны принадлежать корню дом. Жители квартир могут быть как дочерними сущностями (если важен только факт их наличия например), так и корнями, если вы с ними например работаете как то сложнее.

Дочернюю сущность можно делать аналогично DTO - буквально сам факт наличия дочерней и в ней ссылка на другой корень. Т.е. компания (root) - оцениваемые дома (child), где структура типа child содержит буквально ссылку на дом и возможно id для хранения в базе. Потом в такой child можно добавлять примечания, какие то оценки мб, что угодно. К дому они при этом явно не относятся.

Условно:

```
class Company
{
  List<CompanyHouse> Houses
}

class CompanyHouse
{
  House
  Note
}

class House
{ ... }
```

Comment: Дом без компании не может существовать, он сам сущность но не корень, но нужно уметь редактировать список домов компании. Получается агрегат состоит из 3 уровней вложенности (что допускается DDD), Company- root. House-entity. WallMaterial - valueObject. valueObject для House будет больше.  если рассматривать такую структуру домена, то как с ней работать в репозитории. Распишите пожалуйста пример.

Comment: @Aldmi если у вас дома действительно не могут быть сами по себе - то ваш второй пример как раз таки полностью соответствует DDD. И в этом нет ничего плохого. В такой ситуации у вас на уровне сохранения компании остается возможность валидировать занесенные дома. И только компания может это делать, как корень.

Comment: Для каждого корня нужен свой репозиторий, в моем случае репозиторий один для Company. Соответственно companyRepository.AddHouseInCompanyAsync(1, new House(...)).   Я вас правильно понял, что такое допустимо? Или вы имелли ввиду работу через корень агрегации   company.Houses.Add(newHouse);  companyRepository.Save(company);

Comment: @Aldmi второе - `company.Houses.Add(newHouse); companyRepository.Save(company); `

Comment: Понял вас. то-есть всегда сохраняем весь корень? даже если он достаточно большой и изменения маленькие. Или вы имеете в виду что оптимизацию сохранения должен брать на себя репозиторий?

Comment: @Aldmi это сложный вопрос. На деле, DDD ничего не говорит про технологии и какие то оптимизации. Если всё плохо, то оптимизация в любом случае просочится и в репозиторий и в сам корень, но в идеале - только репозиторий.

Comment: Да тут согласен с вами, каждая статья про DDD начинается с фразы что это не про Perfomance. Но все же, обычно все самое медленное связанно с досупом к БД, а тут мы еще усугубляем этот вопрос.

Comment: Пытаюсь представить WebApi. Где вначале мы считали весь агрегат и отдали его на  FrontEnd. Далее поступает PUT запрос на изменение номера дома в котором будет содержатся CompanyId, HouseId, NewHouseAddreess. И пермым действием нам придется прочитать и БД весь агрегат var company= companyRepository.GetById(1); потом что-то поменять и сохранить весь агрегат.

Comment: @Aldmi звучит допустимо. На сервере потом придётся вытащить компанию, найти нужный дом у неё внутри и поправить адрес. Не очень красиво, но вполне в духе DDD.

Comment: вот и мне кажется что если бизнес логики мало в домене, а операций с БД много, то и не стоит использовать DDD. Ну или взять что то полезное, например структуру самого домена (валидацию, ограниченный доступ и т.д.), доменных сервисов и событий.  Но вот доступ к слою данных построить на обычной схеме репозитория с кучей атомарных (оптимизированных) методов.

Comment: Кстати тема DDD тесно связанна с CQRS. Возможно в CQRS вся эта кухня с БД выглядит оптимальнее?

Comment: @Aldmi если вам нужна оптимальность - то оба ваших варианта обязаны быть доступны

Comment: Спасибо, за обсуждение и ответы!!